# Using LAST_INSERT_ID() via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, lastinsertid

When I execute the following in the MySQL console, it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO videos (embed_code) VALUES ('test code here');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

But, when I execute the above queries via PHP, the result is empty.

Under the data abstraction, I am using a database access class named `DB`. This is how I have tried the above queries via PHP:

```
$embedCode = htmlentities($_POST['embed_code']);

//Insert video in database **WORKS**
DB::query("INSERT INTO videos (embed_code) VALUES ('$embedCode');");

//Retrieve id **DOES NOT WORK**
$row = DB::getSingleRow("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
$videoId = $row[0];
```

It is not reliable for me to select the new id by the embed_code, as the embed_code could be repeated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't your database class contain a function to grab the last insert ID? Try mysql_insert_id() otherwise instead.

http://nl.php.net/mysql_insert_id

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I'm using PDO and it has a `lastInsertId()` method! I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function called `mysql_insert_id` which will give you the same result as the query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated functions for this - you shouldn't be using the SQL version as it doesn't work.

In the MySQL library you should use the [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function, whereas the mysqli object has an [insert-id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php) property. This of course may already be exposed in whatever DB class you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with PHP's [`mysql_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.

I think what's happening is that each `DB::query` call is in a different transaction, hence, `$row` is being empty. Maybe you can read `DB:query` documentation to try running both calls within the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id is deprecated.  So I think this thread needs to be updated.

Comment: This should've been a comment, not an answer. Although `mysql_insert_id` is depreciated, `mysqli_insert_id` is not.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id is marked as deprecated since PHP 5.5.0.

In this example uid is the primary key of the table videos.

```
$row = DB::getMultipleRows("SELECT uid FROM videos WHERE uid=LAST_INSERT_ID();");
if (
    isset($row) &&
    is_array($row) &&
    isset($row['0']) &&
    is_array($row['0']) &&
    isset($row['0']['uid'])
) {
    $videoId = $row['0']['uid'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return lastInsertId of PDO to outer of your class . example:

```
class DB
{
    public $last_insert_id;
    function x()
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($Query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->last_insert_id = $db->lastInsertId();
    }    
}
```