# Using last_insert_id();

Tags: php, mysql

I did SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO a_schedule (par_smal_meet) VALUES (20150277); SET @E=last_insert_id();
```

If I just use PHPmyadmin interface it is OK, but if I put it in PHP code like this

```
    $query  = "INSERT INTO a_schedule (par_smal_meet) VALUES (20150277); SET @E=last_insert_id();"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @E=last_insert_id()' at line 1"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using LAST\_INSERT\_ID() via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425625/using-last-insert-id-via-php)

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_query` accepts only **ONE** query at once.

So split your string into multiple calls

Note: every query **MUST NOT** contain `;` in the end